# Close process using a file on windows

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, process

I would want to close all the programs which are using a file on Windows. I've an example of what I want on Linux :

```
pids=`lsof | grep $fic | grep -v "grep" | tr -d '\t' | cut -d" " -f2`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just a side-note, the above command can be simplified: `lsof FILENAME | awk 'NR>1{print $2}'`

Comment: See OpenFiles command. NB Windows doesn't maintain this info as standard (except network opened files). You have to turn it on using openfiles command and reboot. Look at list or csv format options for full path of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change tag from bash to batch
and Install [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655)

This will solve the purpose